# Nothing returned by Angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a [randomizer-web-app](http://random-number.tk/) that serves you random numbers. But clearly something is wrong. The relevant part of my code is as under:

```js
.controller('randController', function() {
      this.minimum = null;
      this.maksimum = null;
      this.desAntall = null;
      this.visDes = false;
      this.setDes = function (x) {
          this.visDes = x;
      };
      this.checkDes = function (x) {
          return this.visDes === x;
      };
      this.tilfeldig = function () {
          return (Math.round((Math.random()*this.maksimum + this.minimum)*this.desAntall)/this.desAntall);
      };
  })
```

```html
<div class="content kalkulator" id="expocalc">

      <section ng-controller="randController as rand">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li>
                  <a href="" ng-click="rand.setDes(false)" ng-class="{active:rand.visDes===false}">Hele tall</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="" ng-click="rand.setDes(true)" ng-class="{active:rand.visDes===true}">Desimaltall</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <input ng-model="rand.minimum" type="number" placeholder="Minste tall"><br>
          <div class="tiny"></div>
          <input ng-model="rand.maksimum" type="number" placeholder="Største tall"><br>
          <div class="tiny"></div>
          <input ng-show="rand.checkDes(true)" ng-model="rand.desAntall" type="number" placeholder="Antall desimaler"><br>
          <pre>Tilfeldig tall = {{rand.tilfeldig}}</pre>
      </section>

        <a name="help"></a>
    </div>
```

I'm really struggling to understand whats wrong. I would be very grateful if someone could tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
{{ rand.tilfeldig() }}
```

instead of

```
{{ rand.tilfeldig }}
```

Comment: Obviously, I almost always make that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to (Anik Islam Abhi's answer explains how you can get it working) use an expression that returns different values for the same input / state (because of your `Math.random()` calls) and will max out your digest iterations (just check your console log after making the change suggested by Anik Islam Abhi).

The right way to do what you want would be to either have a button that calls the `tilfeldig` function to set the random value to a variable in the scope, or within the `tilfeldig` function, check the current values of `minimum`, `maksimum` and `desAntall` and return the previously calculated result if the values have not changed.